# Arabic text is not getting saved in database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, arabic

When i am giving input through TextBox and storing in database like:

```
"Under ( امارات .) english"
```

so what is actually getting stored :

```
 "Under ( ??.?????.) english"
```

Even i have used datatype as nvarchar(Max).How to resolve it? Please answer me as soon as possible. Thanks.

Comment: Works on SO. (I just copied and pasted the text in this comment textbox and it works). Maybe you need to rephrase your question?

Comment: yes it is working. but now what is happening that: when displaying in grid i m receiving same "??.????" in place of Arabic text

Comment: Please check in the database table what is actually getting saved. For special characters or languages like Arabic, Marathi, Hindi, etc.  You have to use nvarchar data-type in your database.

Comment: yes even in my database "??.????" is getting saved, i have used nvarchar(MAX) datatype. if i m directy entering arabic text in database so its working gud but when entering from textbox and saving in table so i m getting this garbage text

Comment: Could you give use the code that 'gets' the text from the textbox and stores the information in the database ? I'm guessing that somewhere along the line (most probably in the INSERT statement) you're implicitly converting the data.

Comment: you most change all collation in your columns of tables of database.my answer help you.because i am from Iran and i had the same problem and fixed that with this query.

Comment: Yes while inserting from the code,you have to use: insert into tbl(col1) values(N'text').  You have to use N as Prefix. This may help you.

Answer (score 1):

Try N'Unicode data'

```
N'Under ( امارات .) english'
```

instead of simple

```
'Under ( امارات .) english'
```

when you are inserting data. N here means national.

Comment: yes in my database by default collation is: "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" which is non unicode. I have used N'Under ( امارات .) english' in the text box and saved now it is actually saved as N'Under ( ?????? .) english'. Still i am getting question mark

Comment: No, try it this way `INSERT INTO Employees VALUES(N'ديتا', ...)`, more info: http://databases.aspfaq.com/general/why-do-some-sql-strings-have-an-n-prefix.html

Comment: no actually i am using LinqtoSql for databases . i am just using insertonsubmit(), to insert data. how to put this statement there?

Comment: L2S adds this N automatically to the final produced SQL, the same as EF. Change your data type to `nvarchar` and then update the mappings in the VS.NET to reflect these changes.

Answer (score 1):

Hoping this sheds some light on why you need to store this as Unicode (*N*varchar) [as suggested by VahidN] and why this has ABSOLUTELY NOTHING to do with Collation (as (was) suggested elsewhere)

Try the following code:

```
CREATE TABLE t_test (
                      txt       varchar(1000) COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN,
                      arabic    varchar(1000)   COLLATE Arabic_100_CI_AI_KS_WS,
                      chinese   varchar(1000)   COLLATE Chinese_Simplified_Pinyin_100_CI_AI,
                      ntxt      nvarchar(1000) COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN,
                      narabic   nvarchar(1000)   COLLATE Arabic_100_CI_AI_KS_WS,
                      nchinese  nvarchar(1000)   COLLATE Chinese_Simplified_Pinyin_100_CI_AI,                      
                   )
GO
INSERT t_test (txt, arabic, chinese, ntxt, narabic, nchinese) 
VALUES ('Under ( امارات .) english',
        'Under ( امارات .) english',
        'Under ( امارات .) english',
        N'Under ( امارات .) english',
        N'Under ( امارات .) english',
        N'Under ( امارات .) english')

SELECT * FROM t_test
```

Answer (score 1):

select projectname then  rightclick then proparties then setting then select the conniction string click in column value then choose .... screen connection proparties will appear on this screen choose advanced then choose character and wright utf8 then choose treat blobs as utf8 change value to true all arabic data will transfer will to my sql.